# SUSE VM looking for wrong partition Ids

Tags: linux, hyper-v, hard-drive, mount, opensuse

I've got a SUSE instance running on a Hyper-V (Win Server 2008 R2) host.
Initial install was fine. After setting up Apache, MySQL, etc... I shut down the VM and snapshotted it (So I could revert if something went wrong).

After the snapshot, the system won't boot.

Specifically I get....

[image: Startup, unable to find HDD]

If I choose "no" (do not attempt to use `...-part1`), it dumps me to a prompt I'm unfamiliar with (`$`). If I answer yes, it waits for `-part1` for a few seconds, fails and drops me to the same prompt.

in either case, I get:

```
sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control on this shell
```

I seem to have an extremely limited toolset (presumably the build-in shell commands?)

If I do an `ls -al /dev/disk/by-id` I get the following:

[image: ls -al --color /dev/disk/by-id]

I'm not sure how to proceed - as far as I can see, the HDD is being recognised by the VM (Otherwise, I wouldn't get this far), but the Id of the partition(s) its looking for to mount is incorrect (Note that the Ids listed vary after the `20202020` part).

How can I either tell Linux to use the new Ids or (failing that), change the Ids to match what Linux is expecting?

Addendum: After more Googling, it seems this might be due to a problem upgrading. I did use YAST to install an "Important" update pre-reboot, so this might also be the cause. Of course, now I'm not 100% sure what version is running. `cat /proc/version` results in:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your snapshotting changed the device ids. Maybe you unintentionally cloned the system? Anyhow, this should help:

At the grub menue (thats where you choose which OS/Kernel you boot, often it also has a rescue option), move the cursor to stop it from automatically continueing with the default optin. Then choose the default option and add `root=/dev/sda1`. Hit Enter, this should boot. On my system I could then log in as root (in text mode). Edit the files `/boot/grub/menu.list` and `/etc/fstab`, replacing each occurence of `disk/by/id[...]-part` with `sda`. This should get you device names like `/dev/sda1`. Reboot, and everything should be fine. You might want to consider checking your grub2 config, so that a kernelupdate would not destroy your menu.lst.

Comment: I actually solved it by editing the Ids in the boot line of of grub menu - but you certainly pointed me in the right direction. Once the systemwas up, I edited as suggested and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I had exactly this problem with the cloning of a VM. Thanks!